# unlogic FOR loop in cmd

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, command-line, cmd

Basically I just want to use a variable instead of permament value.

I have a for Loop, and it works.

```
set OS_ROOT=%systemdrive%

for /f "delims= " %%A IN ('DIR E:\BACKUP /A:D /O:-D /TW /B') 
DO (xcopy/e E:\BACKUP\%%A %OS_ROOT%\TempFestplatte)
```

but as soon as I implement variable:

```
SET STICK_ROOT=%CD:~0,3%
```

which happends to be "E:\", and use it in my loop:

```
for /f "delims= " %%A IN ('DIR %STICK_ROOT%\BACKUP /A:D /O:-D /TW /B') 
DO (xcopy/e %STICK_ROOT%\BACKUP\%%A %OS_ROOT%\TempFestplatte)
```

it doesn't work any moore. and it is only after 'DIR (...)

WHY?

Comment: You're doing `DIR E:\\Backup` which will give "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." Change `SET STICK_ROOT=%CD:~0,3%` to `SET STICK_ROOT=%CD:~0,2%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid double backslash in reference to root folder of drive.

```
:: Set variable in terms of current directory drive
set "STICK_ROOT=%cd:~0,2%"

:: Set variable in terms of current batch file drive
set "STICK_ROOT=%~d0"
```

Not sure which of the two will better fit in your case.